# Validation XML for QDomDocument. How can I check it?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, validation

Is this [XML](http://pastebin.com/ghWQrPzq) is valid? I ask this question, because i don't load this document with .setContent() for QDomDocument in Qt.

Comment: So, basically you have a piece of XML and you would like us to validate it for you? (you found this webpage, how didn't you find the countless XML validators???)

Comment: You realize you can get the error message out of setContent(), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. According to W3's XML validator, the name of the topmost element much match the name of the doctype declaration.